# Is it possible to make a variable that will point to the text in a file, or to write to a file every time a variable changes without a while loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in python. To save all the data I need for every guild the bot has access to, I am using the `json` module and a JSON file. I am reading from the file only once, and putting its content into a dictionary when I press run in python. I also want to write that same dictionary to the file, but do it efficiently. Since writing to a file upon killing the terminal is not easily achievable, making a pointer to the file's text (so every time the dictionary changes, the file's text updates, and vice versa) or updating the file's text every time my dictionary changes seemed convenient. However, while I do not know if the first option is possible, the second one is, but doing it with a while loop seems like a super inefficient option (making it slower than 1 second could make scenarios such as the dictionary getting changed, and me closing the terminal before the wait time is up (resulting in the dictionary not getting saved to the file) possible). I need to know if there is an efficient way to achieve this.

*For now I am writing to the file every time when I change the dictionary by calling the update file function (just dumps the content of the dictionary to the file), however, I need to know if there is a more efficient way.*

Comment: Not impossible, but it would be very hard to make small changes in a json file. Its a single, serialized string where order matters. Rewriting on each change to the dict is the way to go. But it is slow and there much better protocols out there to handle the problem. A database may be a good choice. sqlite comes with python and may be a good choice.

Comment: Wow, you didn't paste the "How to write a good question" link or question my existence. Thank you for such a straightforward answer! I'll do some research on sqlite, I did come across it while searching for ways to write data to a file, but JSON seemed like an easier option.

Comment: As for efficiency, its a matter of how large the data set is and how often the updates need to happen. Lets say you are dealing with 10K every second. That's not a big deal. File writes go to the system cache in RAM before going to the disk so you won't notice it.